# Pass attributes between Get and Post controller, but not in the URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a POST controller which takes a form and performs some calculations based on the given input.
I.e
If the form submits two variables a and b , the POST method takes these two variables and creates Integer c=a+b.
Now I want to pass this Integer C to my GET controller, because when I return the model and view from my get controller, I need to pass C as an object to be able to use it in my Thymeleaf template.

What is the best way to achieve that ?
I use return new ModelAndView("redirect:/path") from my POST method, and then the GET method maps that link.
I do not want to pass the variable in the URL.
I tried using redirect attributes like addFlashAttributes but after a refresh I lose the value, and I need to keep the value displayed in the page.

Sample code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public ModelAndView sumValue(@Valid Sum sum, BindingResult bindingResult,RedirectAttributes redir) {
    long firstClient=compare.getId();
    long varA= compare.getA();
    long varB= compare.getB();

    Long c= varA+ varB.;

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(
            "redirect:/user?firstId=" + firstClient);

    return modelAndView;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "firstId" })
public ModelAndView comparison(@RequestParam(value = "firstId", required = true) String firstI) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("firstClient", firstId);
    //here i want to add as an Object varC from the Post controller so I can use it in my thymeleaf
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: always use forward..

Comment: On refresh you will of course lose the value. What do you expect, who will cache the value for you? All variables are request scope. Next time some one wants User details, he has to provide userId.

Comment: bsingh : Instead of redirect I should use Forward ? Cuz I get an error.
@mdev I know, I meant that if I pass it using addObject and then redirect, it gets passed in the URL and I Dont want that. Whereas if I use redirect attributes with that method, I can pass it and use it, but once. And i need it more than that.

Comment: @MonG probably can try session object http://www.javaroots.com/2013/08/how-to-get-session-object-in-spring-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:

1. You could just forward the page.
2. You could store the value in the session using `setAttribute` and get it in the Get-controller using `getAttribute`.
3. You could obfuscate the result by create a static `Map<Long, Long>`-classfield storing as Key the time and as value the result of the calculation. If the key is too old, remove it. Transport the key as you transport the `firstClient`.

For security reasons I would suggest to only use the second method instead of the third.